# Unable to reimport py file after several time looped

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, import, destroy

I'm not able to loop the code, here is my code and i hope to let my code able to load another py module when button pressed but when i cycle 2nd time it will be ended even though cache has not written.

Here are the two .py file i used:

```py
#test.py
import tkinter
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
top = tkinter.Tk()
def next():
    top.destroy()
    import test2
B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = next)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

```py
#test2.py
import tkinter
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

top = tkinter.Tk()

def next1():
    top.destroy()
    import test

B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = next1)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: `import test` will import `test` module *only once*, the subsequent call of the same statement will not import `test` module again.  Same applies to `import test2`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clarification, may i know is there any alternative way to get the result i wish?

Answer (score 0):

`import test` will import `test` module *only once*, the subsequent calls of the same statement will not import `test` module again.  Same applies to `import test2` as well.

You need to put the required code inside a function, then import that function and execute it instead:

## test.py

```py
import sys

sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

def main():
    import tkinter
    from test2 import main2

    def next():
       top.destroy()
       main2()

    top = tkinter.Tk()
    B = tkinter.Button(top, text="Hello", command=next)
    B.pack()
    top.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## test2.py

```py
import sys

sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

def main2():
    import tkinter
    from test import main

    def next1():
       top.destroy()
       main()

    top = tkinter.Tk()
    B = tkinter.Button(top, text="Hello 2", command=next1)
    B.pack()
    top.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main2()
```